# Is Rex real K9 working dog?

Tags: character, hudson-and-rex

In *Hudson & Rex*, is Rex a real K9 working dog that works with a detective in real life? (In Canada)?

As he certainly doesn't look like a family dog or is he?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### NO

A glance at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudson_%26_Rex#Casting) tells us

> Diesel vom Burgimwald (Rex) is a 15th descendant from the shepherd who starred in the 1990s Austrian show Inspector Rex that Hudson & Rex is based on. Two other German Shepherds, Izzy and Iko, who are nephews of Diesel vom Burgimwald, stand-in for some of the stunts. Diesel vom Burgimwald had mobility training before being cast as Rex. This is Diesel's first show according to his owner/handler Sherri Davis and training continues on non-shooting days in preparation for future scripts. While on set Diesel has full star treatment with his own trailer, chef, and chauffeur. Diesel is an honorary firefighter with the St. John's Regional Fire Department (SJRFD) as a result of the episode Fast Eddie's.